# Can I check in the DOM if some variable of the controller is empty before add content using AngularJs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I need to check if my object room.connected has some data, if not empty, then print a ng-repeat in the DOM, in that way:

```
 <a ng-repeat="item in room.connected | limitTo: 15;", title="{{item.username}}">
    <img src="/upload/avatar/{{item.avatar}}"/>
 </a>
```

I need to check  there because room.connected is a object depending of a database and in some cases the result is empty, so the list print images without sources. 
I know that I can't combine logic in the view, but I need some ideas for doing what I need.

Comment: Shouldn't the `<img>` be inside the `<a>` tag?

Comment: Yes. In fact it is so. The example was extracted from a jade format and I don't adapted correctly. Let me fix that.

Comment: if the object you iterate through with ng-repeat is empty, it won't print anything. But, you can always do something like `ng-if="room.connected"`

Comment: Exactly...I'm confused how you are ending up with images with no source. That should be impossible given what you have included in the question. Unless you are saying that `item.avatar` is empty. In that case you could, as suggested, use `ng-if`.